# Brightcove Smart Player API - hide seek controls

Tags: javascript, brightcove

I'm upgrading someone else's code from the flash-only player API to the Smart Player API and I'm having a heck of a time trying to find out how to hide the seek controls on either player (both flash and HTML5 versions).

The old code that works is like this:

```
exp = player.getModule(APIModules.EXPERIENCE);
phead = exp.getElementByID("playhead");
phead.setVisible(false);
```

The new code that I've been trying to translate that into is like this:

```
BCL.experience = BCL.player.getModule(BCL.APIModules.EXPERIENCE);
BCL.experience.getElementByID('playhead').setVisible(false);
```

The error is that there is no method getElementByID and I've confirmed that it doesn't look like a typical DOM object with my console. Does anyone know how I can hide or disable the seek controls on the flash and html5 player?

I'm at a total loss for how this is done and I feel that I've read every page of their API documentation without success.